# Issue when Connecting C# program to Hive server on Linux VM

Tags: c#, linux, hadoop, hive

I have downloaded Hive odbc driver for .net ,then I created DSN with following parameters:

1. Host : IP address of my linux VM
2. Port No: 10000 default
3. Hive Server 1
4. Data source name:Hadoop

when I test DSN it show test completed Successfully and connected to Hive server of Linux VM.

but when I tried to connect C# program to same Linux VM's Hive Server with above parameters it give me error in  connection string i.e

> data source not found and no default driver specified

```
on conn.open();
```

Please Help Me..:)

Comment: Post some code. Show us what you actually, specifically tried so far.

Comment: Hi, @nyerguds - I am following below link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/738141/How-to-Communicate-to-Hadoop-via-Hive-using-NET-Cs

Comment: Did you actually install and configure that Hive ODBC Driver? Looks to me the config of that thing is your real issue.

Comment: Hi, @nyerguds - I am using HP laptop X64 , i downloaded the Hive ODBC driver as mentioned in article.then I statrted my linux VM on windows 10 . I satrted hadoop cluster as well as hive db .and copy linux vm IP in windows dns (set odbc 64) and it shows me connected.but when i create c# program to connect same hive db it shows me the error.